# How can I fix this counter I wrote used to find the number of blocked calls?

Tags: python, numpy, counter

**What my code is meant to do:**

Simulate 100 voice calls that occur over an N channel network and calculate the grade of service (that is, the percentage of blocked calls) over a period of 60 minutes.

**My Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#Uniformly distributed start times
startTimes = np.random.randint(0,60,100)
startTimes.sort()

#Average call time for 100 people 
callDuration = np.random.poisson(20, 100)

channelCounter = 0;
blockedCounter = 0;

endTimes = np.add(callDuration, startTimes)

numberChannels = 1

for x in range(0,60): 

    for y in range(0, startTimes.size):

        if startTimes[y] == x: 
            if channelCounter < numberChannels:
                channelCounter=channelCounter+1

            elif channelCounter == numberChannels: 

                blockedCounter = blockedCounter + 1

        if (endTimes[y] == x):
            if channelCounter >= 1:
                channelCounter=channelCounter-1
```

**My Approach:**

I generate a uniform distribution of 100 call start times beginning from 0 min to 60 minutes.

I generate a random poisson distribution of 100 call durations for an average call time of 20 minutes.

I set my channel counter variable and blocked counter variables to 0.

Finally, I create another array consisting of the sum of call start time + average call duration to get the call end time.

The pseudo code logic behind blocked counter incrementing is as follows:

```
if number of channels occupied < number channels available:
    put a call through 
else if number of channels occupied == number channels available ( ie full):
    call is dropped so counter incremements 

if a call that is ongoing finishes: 
    decrement number of channels occupied
```

My blocked counter isn't incrementing as I expect it to. I have a vague idea of what is going wrong but I don't know how to fix it. With the current values im inputting, I should expect to see a value of around 95 for blocked counter. What I get however is a value that hovers around 70-75.

If anyone spots where im going wrong, I would greatly appreciate it!

[Screen shot of the data im working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtpKJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so your problem here is, that you take ANY `endTime` value, which happens on given minute as a sign of freeing a channel. Whereas some of these were actually blocked. Which is why you are inflating the total number of non blocked calls. What you rather want is to compute number of non-overlapping <`startTime`, `endTime`> intervals (assuming possible max overlapping calls at given minute equal to `numberChannels` AND order priority of calls)

So assuming one channel you can do:

```py
minute=0
nonBlockedCounter=0

while(minute<=60):
    minute = min(startTimes[minute<=startTimes])
    if(minute>=0):
        nonBlockedCounter+=1
        minute=endTimes[startTimes==minute][0]
blockedCounter=100-nonBlockedCounter
print(blockedCounter)
```

Output is around 96-97 most often.

Comment: God, I spent like 6 hours trying to debug this.Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it :)

Comment: This is very cheeky of me to ask but would you be able to show me how to make it work for N channels? Im struggling to implement the functionality to allow overlapping calls

Comment: Im just wondering if im able to get it to handle N channels without having to resort to multithreading as I have no experience with it.

Comment: Nvm, got it working fully without resorting to threading :) Your example helped me a ton.

Comment: No worries. I had an idea of doing the above in for loop (```for ... While ...```) iterating over each channel with removal of counted ```startTimes``` and ```endTimes``` but didn't get close to actually coding it. Glad to hear all works for you though.